# How to marshal this c struct and call its method in c#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I've seen answers similar to this in other places, but none of those solutions are working and usually they are slightly different questions. I haven't seen any of the other questions' solutions help here.

I have a dll with a method-parameter of a type of struct containing a uint array, passed to the method as a pointer. Here's what the old c header has:

```
typedef struct HandleArrayType
{
    uint32_t HandleArray[max_number_100];
}HandleArrayType;
typedef HandleArrayType *HandleArrayPtrType;

typedef bool (*type_connectToMultiple)(char *CommaSeparatedString, HandleArrayPtrType ArrayPointer, uint32_t numberOfOpensAttempted) __attribute__((cdecl));
```

We've tried several ways to marshal this, here's the last suggestion we tried and was giving us memory access violations:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct HandleArrayType
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
    public uint[] HandleArray;
}

[DllImport("file", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern bool ConnectToMultiple(string[] nameArray, ref HandleArrayType myStruct, uint numAttempted);
```

I think I also tried something like this before a few times, which does connect, but we were getting one handle instead of two and the handle number was way off (indicating improper marshaling of the should-be struct):

```
[DllImport("file", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern bool ConnectToMultiple(IntPtr commaSepHandlesString, uint[] handles , ref uint numAttempted);
```

(Then when we call this we marshal as an IntPtr for the handles string)
If anyone knows of a way to marshal this properly please post a solution, we are using a crappy workaround right now that will make our process very slow (and speed is a concern).

EDIT: We were able to make our workaround faster by installing a more recent version of the dll, so it isn't a huge problem for us anymore. But the connectToMultiple method is still busted. Still curious to see if it can be made to work

Comment: The `fixed` keyword is helpful... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code#fixed-size-buffers

Comment: The first snippet is a correct declaration for the posted C code.  "numAttempted" is a name that suggests it returns a value.  Which makes the C declaration wrong, should be uint32_t *numberOfOpensAttempted.  For some unguessable reason you seemed to get that right in the second attempt.

Comment: `string[]`? `char *` is rather `string`... Is should be mark as unmanaged LPStr...

Comment: A definitive answer would need more C and the semantics on how it works (+ charset, packing, who allocates, etc.). Anyway something like this should work `static extern bool ConnectToMultiple(string nameArray, ref HandleArrayType myStruct, uint numAttempted);` (and/or change the last to `ref` as Hans told)

Comment: @Selvin I've tried multiple variations of passing strings to that method and for the most part, actually all of them work. IntPtr with marshalas works, LPstr works, and just passing a string itself also works. I have no idea why. Everything seems to work pretty much everywhere, except for the returned handles array, it just always returns some large number that I am pretty sure isn't a real handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the C Declaration is wrong, and `numAttempted` is a pointer. Furthermore, you need to specify the charset of the string, which is normally `LPStr`.

Furthermore, it's unclear if `myStruct` should be `[In, Out] ref` or `[Out] out` or `in`.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct HandleArrayType
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
    public int[] HandleArray;
}

[DllImport("file", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern bool ConnectToMultiple(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string nameArray,
    [In, Out] ref HandleArrayType myStruct,
    [Out] out uint numAttempted);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var handleArrayType = new HandleArrayType();
    bool results = ConnectToMultiple("abc", ref handleArrayType, out var numAttempted);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't actually using a handlearray definition, I was just using a regular array. For some reason it did connect and return "handle" values, but when using the handles later I could see they weren't correct. This was before I had realized the input was a struct and not an actual array. I'll try this one out soon and see what happens

Comment: Also just for clarity, the IntPtr definitely did work since the number of commas in the IntPtr string determines the number returned by "numattempted" in the calls. The only thing that doesnt work is the returned handles

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, the reason it didn't work when you did as `string nameArray` is because you didn't specify charset so it marhsalled as Unicode not ANSI

Comment: I gave this one a try, similar to my last attempt in the OP it did appear to connect, but the handle returned was "2069910436" (and there should be two handles). I think when I did mine the handle was a smaller number like 14000000/15000000 or something but the handle didnt work in either of these cases

Comment: Like other said, could be the Packing is off, or could be `uint32_t` is defined as something else, it's hard to know.

Comment: I think we've established that the dll method is likely bad itself so I cannot "test" the code. However when I used your setup it did "show it connected" so the actual question was probably answered. I have marked it correct. EDIT: well, someone can try making a fake c dll and try it that way but I'm not going to do that at this point

Answer (score -1):

The structure needs to be in unmanaged space.

```
       [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct HandleArrayType
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)]
            public IntPtr[] HandleArray;
        }
        [DllImport("file", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern bool ConnectToMultiple(string nameArray, IntPtr myStruct, uint numAttempted);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HandleArrayType handleArrayType = new HandleArrayType();
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(handleArrayType));
            string nameArray = "abc";
            uint numAttempted = 100;
            bool results = ConnectToMultiple(nameArray, ptr, numAttempted);
        }
```

Comment: Why'd you change the element type inside the array?  The C code is definitely 32-bit integers on any platform.  And no, the structure doesn't need to be in unmanaged memory.

Comment: @BenVoigt : A INTPTR is a 32 bit integer.  It doesn't really make a difference.  I suspect it is really a pointer.

Comment: This resulted in an access violation when calling the connectomultiple method

Comment: Correction: I changed uint numAttempted to ref uint numAttempted and it did also report it connected (returned true and the numattempted changed to 2). However, I have no idea how I am supposed to reference the returned handles since they are hidden behind the intptr. I will look around to see if I can find a way to get the values

Comment: @jdweng: No, an IntPtr is a pointer-sized integer, like `uintptr_t`.  It is not 32-bit everywhere.

Comment: Well, using this method I changed IntPtr[] to uint[] and for some reason, the array wasn't being initialized by default so I added an initializer line before calling ConnectToMultiple. After that it connected and the numattempted changed as it should, but the handles were all still 0 for some reason (even the first one which usually has the 14million+ bad handles).

Comment: Is the boolean returning true?  Try using Powershell to get all handles.  The name you are using may be wrong : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PoshInternals/1.0.31/Content/Handle.ps1

Comment: @jdweng the boolean does return true yes, but I don't trust that boolean since it  returns true even when I type in fake strings for the names (IE, "fake1,fake2,fake3"). It does the same thing for the numattempted, if there is one comma numattempted will be 2, for two commas it will have numattempted = 3 and so on. But in all cases those names are not real and it could not have connected to them. At this point I think the dll is just bad (for that method, anyways)

Comment: True means you did not get any errors.  Not finding a name is not an error.  It is just a query with no results.

Comment: @jdweng actually the documentation states: "True if every part was identified and has a valid handle.
False if there were any errors identifying or connecting to any of the parts." In practice I have learned this method always returns true regardless of how many parts were identified or connected to so the return value just isn't useful. The numAttempted does match your description and is usually correct. Handles should be 0 if the connection failed and a valid number otherwise, but that never worked either. We have all learned that int should be ref also, so the c is definitely wrong.